# Value too long for type character varying(15)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I have a microservice which receives events and saves them in a Postgres database with EntityFramework.
Some of these events result in the error `Value too long for type character varying(15)`.
There are only 2 columns that are restricted to a length of 15 but all the events that have caused an error contain valid values within these restrictions for both of those properties.

Sadly the error doesn't tell me which column is the culprit.
Is there a way to get more information?

Comment: without having more details, it is a bit hard to guess, but I hope someone has had some similar experience to give some input.

Comment: Do you receive result always in same format?

Comment: Look at the Postgres log, it should have a more detailed error message.